# Msg 9002 - The transaction log for database [dbName] is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

The database in question is set to SIMPLE recovery mode. The disk is not out of space. The database is essentially read only. I can't change any of its properties or run a checkpoint. The transaction log is not particularly large; only 1.5 MB; and is set to be able to grow.

Full error message:

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 1, Line 4
> The transaction log for database [dbName] is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'

Things I've tried:

Backing up the log : N/A, set to SIMPLE recovery mode

Changing recovery mode to FULL :

> Alter failed; transaction log is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'

Running a checkpoint :

> Msg 5901, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> One or more recovery units belonging to database '[dbName]' failed to generate a checkpoint. This is typically caused by lack of system resources such as disk or memory, or in some cases due to database corruption. Examine previous entries in the error log for more detailed information on this failure.

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 1, Line 1
> The transaction log for database '[dbName]' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'.

Adding additional log file :

> Alter failed; transaction log is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'

Comment: What do you get if you run `dbcc`?

Comment: You might also check the properties on your database files. They may have a max size set for them and they are full.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn DBCC SQLPERF('logspace') returns 1.492188 MB log size; 116.2304% space used

Comment: @SeanLange autogrowth/maxsize is set to 10%, unlimited

Comment: Ugh. Percent growth is rather awful but not an issue for this discussion. What about DBCC CHECKDB? Any errors?

Comment: `select name, size, max_size, growth, is_percent_growth, is_read_only, is_media_read_only from sys.database_files` what do you get?

Comment: @SeanLange plenty of errors: https://pastebin.com/Hfu6bc6y

Comment: @Charlieface 
name size max_size growth is_percent_growth is_read_only is_media_read_only
dbName_Data 8728960 -1 10 1 0 0
dbName_Log 192 -1 10 1 0 0

Comment: @Charliefacethe recovery mode is already simple. running a checkpoint does not work, as stated in the post

Comment: Do you have a stuck/rolling back transaction that's blocking?
Have you attempted to write anything else to the volume holding the log?(is the volume bad)

Comment: @PatrickHurst not that I'm aware of. There are several other databases on the same disk that are all working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using the following procedure:

- take the database offline
- delete the contents of the .LDF log file
- bring the database online
- follow the procedure outlined in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325761/13094633)

Comment: Please duplicate the essential points here as s quote.

Comment: "delete the contents of the .LDF log file" you probably lost data, which was waiting to be checkpointed. This is not the right answer in most situations.